# C#: Deserialize JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a problem with Deserializing JSON

This is my JSON file

```
{
  "api_result": 1,
  "api_result_msg": "OK",
  "api_data": {
    "api_basic": {
      "api_nickname": "David",
    },
    "api_p_bgm_id": 112,
    "api_parallel_quest_count": 5
  }
}
```

The matching class(generated by special paste in visual studio):

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public int api_result { get; set; }
    public string api_result_msg { get; set; }
    public Api_Data api_data { get; set; }
}

public class Api_Data
{
    public Api_Basic api_basic { get; set; }
    public int api_p_bgm_id { get; set; }
    public int api_parallel_quest_count { get; set; }
}

public class Api_Basic
{
    public string api_nickname { get; set; }
}
```

And my code:

```
    string JJ = "{\"api_result\":1,\"api_result_msg\":\"OK\",\"api_data\":{\"api_basic\":{\"api_nickname\":\"David\"},\"api_p_bgm_id\":112,\"api_parallel_quest_count\":5}}";
    Rootobject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(JJ);
    Api_Basic nickname = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Api_Basic>(JJ);

    Console.WriteLine("result:" + result.api_result_msg);
    Console.WriteLine("nickname:" + nickname.api_nickname);
```

The output:

```
result:OK <---success
nickname: <---fail
```

I tried:

```
Rootobject nickname = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(JJ);
Console.WriteLine(nickname.api_basic.api_nickname);
```

But this doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your second sample it should be `nickname.api_data.api_basic.api_nickname`

Comment: Your JSON is not valid. Remove the comma after `"api_nickname": "David"`

Comment: What do you mean by *doesn't work* ? Does it throw a runtime exception? Does it not compile? Please be more clear and specific

Comment: omg, you solve my problem extremely quick. thank you Ulugbek Umirov Ferhat Sayan, Matias Cicero, Alberto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why performing the deserialization two times?

You only need the first object:

```
string JJ = "{\"api_result\":1,\"api_result_msg\":\"OK\",\"api_data\":{\"api_basic\":{\"api_nickname\":\"David\"},\"api_p_bgm_id\":112,\"api_parallel_quest_count\":5}}";
Rootobject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(JJ);

Console.WriteLine("result:" + result.api_result_msg);
Console.WriteLine("nickname:" + result.api_data.api_basic.api_nickname);
```